# getting "Expected Stream" error while sending envelope from docusign console

Tags: docusignapi

We are opening draft envelope using DocuSign REST API in DocuSign web console from our website, so our user can add/edit tags in document and send envelope directly from docusign site. But while sending envelope we are getting "Expected Stream" error. Can anyone have an idea why this error can come?

Comment: Can you please post some of your code. It is hard to provide an answer with the information you have provided.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code and the exact error message that you're receiving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/tag-and-send-workflow-from-your-app) shows how to use the SenderView method to open the Sender's view on DocuSign for an envelope that you've created in draft mode.

Your user can then tag the document(s) and send off the envelope.